# How to export Dialog Settings between workspace without manual copy of the dialog_settings.xml in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to export the dialog settings of a eclipse dialog between work spaces.

Generally,the dialog settings are persisted in the dialog_settings.xml on the exit/restart of the workspace.

Up to my knowledge the files has to be manually copied from workspace (1)to the desired workspace(2) and to be restarted for the settings to be loaded

file path to be copied:
workspace1.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.search\dialog_settings.xml -->copied to workspace2.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.search

Is there an api provided by eclipse to transfer these settings ?

Comment: No, there is no API to do this.

Comment: Is there any extensions available ? If possible,Is it advisable to export dialog settings to different versions of eclipse?